# Can you use Microsoft Entity Framework with Oracle?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

Is it possible to use Microsoft Entity Framework with Oracle database?

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1395

Answer (score 27, accepted):

DevArt's OraDirect provider now supports entity framework. See http://devart.com/news/2008/directs475.html

Comment: Devart dotConnect for Oracle (formerly OraDirect .NET) now provides support for Entity Framework v4 Release Candidate http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/?p=2062

Comment: You can read more and download trial version of Devart dotConnect for Oracle here  - http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/.

Comment: For Model-first, the devArt dotConnect DDL generation template makes a much more sensible stab at data types than the first-cut Oracle beta (eg: doesn't just make everything Numeric(38,0)). The Oracle template doesn't even generate sequences for identity fields...

Answer (score 81):

**Update**:

Oracle now fully supports the Entity Framework.
Oracle Data Provider for .NET Release 11.2.0.3 (ODAC 11.2)
Release Notes:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/whatsnew.htm#BGGJIEIC

More documentation on Linq to Entities and ADO.NET Entity Framework:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/featLINQ.htm#CJACEDJG

Note: ODP.NET also supports Entity SQL.

Comment: Oracle will likely release a beta refresh at some point in the future. In case the link above breaks, keep an eye on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html for announcements.

Comment: Note that Code-First is NOT supported

Comment: now, in 2013, any driver fully managed .NET for Oracle (EF included) ?

Comment: @Kiquenet  - In 2015 (and probably earlier) Oracle has a managed driver that supports Entity Framework. It's available in NuGet.

Answer (score 11):

Oracle have announced a ["statement of direction"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/oracle-entity-framework-sod-130214.pdf) for ODP.net and the Entity Framework:

In summary, ODP.Net beta around the end of 2010, production sometime in 2011.

Comment: By then V5 of the EF would have shipped, oracle seems to be doing what ever it can get away with to mark it hard to use .net with oracle and Microsoft is doing what ever it can get away with it make it hard to use oracle with .net

Comment: The Oracle website got redesigned and some links got broken. Here is the new link for the Oracle and Entity Framework statement of direction:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/oracle-entity-framework-sod-130214.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Yes. See this [step by step tutorial of Entity Framework, LINQ, and Model-First for the Oracle database (11G), and using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm).

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't know it already, Oracle has released ODP.NET which supports Entity Framework. It doesn't support code first yet though.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "mostly".

We've hit a problem using it where the EF generates code that uses the CROSS and OUTER APPLY operators. [This link shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896273.aspx) that MS knows its a problem with SQL Server previous to 2005 however, they forget to mention that these operators are not supported by Oracle either.

Comment: what EF provider are you using?

Comment: FYI - The APPLY SQL keyword was added to Oracle Database 12c. So eventually this issue will fade away as people move to this version of the database. The scenarios where APPLY shows up are not that common.

Answer (score 1):

Now has a new nuget package, try use it: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/

Comment: Banetti Can I use it in .NET Core 2.2 application?