# Entity Data Model with Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I'm using VS 2008 SP1. I want to create an edmx file using my existing database in Oracle 10g. I tried to add ADO.Net Entity Data Model item, but in the Entity Data Model Wizard, .NET Provider for Oracle does not show up. Can someone suggest a way to connect to existing Oracle database to generate the edmx file? Thanks.

Comment: Some information and links about the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle

Answer (score 0):

you need to install ODAC Beta EntityFramework. Can be downloaded from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html