# WPF Bind a ListView to Oracle Data Source

Tags: wpf, vb.net, oracle, data-binding, odp.net

Here's a part of XAML of the application I'm working on:

```
<ListView Name="lsvCustomerDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding myDataTable}">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Script Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding status}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding date}"/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And the corresponding VB.NET:

```
Class Window1
   Public myDataTable As DataTable

   Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
      Dim objOracleConnection As New OracleConnection("Data Source=DB;User Id=user;Password=password;")
      Dim objOracleCommand As New OracleCommand
      Dim objOracleReader As OracleDataReader

      objOracleConnection.Open()

      objOracleCommand.Connection = objOracleConnection
      objOracleCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customers"
      objOracleReader = objOracleCommand.ExecuteReader()

      Using objOracleConnection
         Dim objOracleAdapter As OracleDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(objOracleCommand.CommandText, objOracleConnection)
         objOracleAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
      End Using
      lsvCustomerDetails.DataContext = myDataTable
      objOracleConnection.Close()
   End If
End Using
```

Is this code correct to fill this table?  If not, why?  Honestly, I've found several perspectives on how to do this sort of thing, some of which are linked below:

[From switchonthecode](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1)
[From csharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/databinding10042007165025pm/databinding.aspx)
[From Allen Mack's blog](http://allen-mack.blogspot.com/2008/01/databinding-generic-list-to-wpf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using LINQ?  It is much easier ...

Add a Data Entity Model to your project. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle) and then use LINQ to do your binding.

Something like:

```
Dim Context as New myOracleEntityModel

myTable = Context.myCustomers.ToList

myItemSource = From i In myTable
               Select i.ID, i.status, i.date

lsvCustomerDetails.ItemSource = myItemSource
```

The only trick is going to be loading the Data Entity model for Oracle.

Comment: That's certainly cleaner and much nicer than what I had.  I'll look into it.