# Entity Framework provider for Oracle

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I want to use linq to sql classes generated by VS or entitty framework, for Oracle databases, how can i do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use Microsoft Entity Framework with Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 and use Oracle 10g, then you can use [a provider for Oracle](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFOracleProvider/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1395) from MSDN Code Gallery. It is compatible with EF.

You can't access Oracle with LINQ only, without using Entity Framework.

There is [another provider on CodePlex](http://eforacle.codeplex.com/), based on the sample provided below, which works also with Oracle 9i.

Finally, you may be interested in the related Stack Overflow question: [Can you use Microsoft Entity Framework with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle)

Comment: i have vs2010 and many versions of oracle servers, so, i want some universal solution

Answer (score 4):

"You can't access Oracle with LINQ only, without using Entity Framework."

Why not? Try to use third party providers - Devart or DataDirect.

I recommend you to try Devart provider - http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/.