# Will Microsoft Entity FrameWork 3.5/4.0 Works with Oracle Database?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Anyone tried connecting Oracle Database from Microsoft Entity FrameWork 3.5/4.0 ?
If Yes, Please let me know the limitations ?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this useful ... [Can you use Microsoft Entity Framework with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle)