# Any better way to use Oracle/MySQL with .NET Entity Framework?

Tags: mysql, oracle, entity-framework

I wonder the simplicity of working with **Microsoft SQL** database server with .NET Entity Framework. Is there a possible way to use it with **Oracle** & **MySQL** database servers?

Comment: Have you seen [this stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework) question for MySQL?

Comment: Not a big fan of the entity framework, maybe try NHibernate http://nhforge.org/ or SubSonic http://www.subsonicproject.com/

Comment: @Sean would NHibernate and subsonic support this features?

Comment: @Dirk it has some good point about MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another ORM, like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) which supports Microsoft SQL, Oracle, and MySQL, among many others.

If you want/need to stick with EF, there are already questions on SO about using it [with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76488/using-mysql-with-entity-framework) and [with Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle).

Comment: is NHibernate database independent?

Comment: @Muneer: Pretty much, yes. It supports all the database servers [mentioned here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-optional-dialects) (that list is a bit outdated, because it does support the most recent versions of SQL server and Oracle, even if they're not mentioned there).

Comment: Great; Let me have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Data Access Components for .NET (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html) includes also Oracle Data Provider for .NET 4 11.2.0.2.40.

A nice tutorial how to use Model-First approach can be found at http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm.

Good luck,

LM

Answer (score 0):

A list of Oracle providers for Entity Framework can be found here: 
[Comparison of Entity Framework compatible providers for Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8029000/38368)

And for MySQL these are available:
http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/entityframework.html
http://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet/