# What (commercial) Entity Framework 4.0 LINQ providers are available?

Tags: .net, linq, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Oracle is currently building a LINQ provider for Entity Framework 4.0, but it is still in beta (and it still sucks is my personal experience). So we are searching for good alternatives to query Oracle databases using Entity Framework version 4.0.

What is your experience with (commercial) Entity Framework 4.0 LINQ providers and what can you advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used DevArt dotConnect for Oracle.  It has a reasonable price tag and works OK for me.

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle), there is also a provider from DataDirect.  I think it's more expensive, I haven't used it so I can't say if it's worth the price difference.