# Maintain a single database connection in multiple forms

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net

I have this c# application where the user needs to login through the first form. If validation returns true form2 opens up .

I want to maintain a single connection through all these forms with the same user credentials as entered in form1.I am using ODP.NET to connect to oracle 11g.

Thanks.

Comment: @otiel i connect to the db from form1 but i am unable to use the same connection to the db in form2.I need to reconnect.Is there any way in c# to make this happen?

Comment: As pointed by *Niyoko Yuliawan* in his answer, you should close your SqlConnection as soon as you finished your query. Thus, you don't have to use a single connection through all your forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql connection in .NET is managed by [connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). So if you instantiate new connection objects, it reuses old closed physical connection.

in form1

```
using(var c = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
     //use connection here
}
```

in form2

```
using(var c = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    //use connecion here
}
```

form1 and form2 use same physical connection to database

connection pooling also available for [Oracle Data Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

or maybe you interested in [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Static Connectionstring class like
if you declare a Static class with properties of Sqlconnection you can access it in any form or any other class directly here is a sample of class

```
public static class Connection
    {
        private static SqlConnection sqlconn;
        public static SqlConnection getconnection() {
            if (sqlconn==null)
               sqlconn = new SqlConnection("Connectionsting.");
            return sqlconn;
        }


    }
```