# Is there a better way to map Objects from a database query to an object?

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, extension-methods

I would like to know if there is a better way to solve this problem that I am overlooking. (I'm looking for a second opinion)

I want to create a generic and easy way to bind objects to database reader queries using "Oracle.DataAccess.Client".

In order to do this I initially wanted to create an object which inherited from OracleCommand; however, OracleCommand is a sealed object.

To deal with this I decided to create an extension method which attempts to map objects to generic columns in the database for each row.

EDIT : In my scenario, I know what the database will look like; however, I will not know where the database is before run time. i.e. The database may have been transferred ahead of time and the end user will specify the credentials for the database at run time.

Here is the implementation:

```
public static T[] Bind<T>(this OracleCommand oe, Binding binding, CommandBehavior Behavior = CommandBehavior.Default)
    {
        List<T> ret = new List<T>();

        using (var reader = oe.ExecuteReader(Behavior))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                T unknownObj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                for (int i = 0; i < binding.GetBindCount(); i++)
                {
                    var propinfo = unknownObj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
                    var prop = propinfo.Find((p) => p.Name == binding.GetBindValue(i, true));
                    prop.SetValue(unknownObj, reader[binding.GetBindValue(i, false)]);
                }
                ret.Add(unknownObj);
            }
        }
        return ret.ToArray();
    }
}

public class Binding
{

    List<BindingMap> _map = new List<BindingMap>();


    public void AddBind(String VariableName, String ColumnName)
    {
        _map.Add(new BindingMap(VariableName, ColumnName));
    }
    public String GetBindValue(int index, bool IsVariable = true)
    {
        var a = _map.ToArray();
        return (IsVariable) ? a[index].Variable : a[index].Column;
    }

    public int GetBindCount()
    {
        return _map.Count;
    }
}

public class BindingMap
{
    public String Column;
    public String Variable;

    public BindingMap(String v, String c)
    {
        Variable = v;
        Column = c;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this that I've overlooked, or is this a sound?

The way it would be used in real code is like this :

```
 static void Main()
    {           
        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.AddBind("CreatedBy", "Create_by");


        using (var Conn = new OracleConnection())
        {
            Conn.ConnectionString = od.Options.GetConnectionString();
            using (var Command = new OracleCommand())
            {
                Command.Connection = Conn;
                Command.CommandText = "Select * From Accounts";

                Conn.Open();

                var a = Command.Bind<Account>(b);
                foreach (Account e in a)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.CreatedBy);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public String CreatedBy
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, use an ORM? You don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `Is there a better way to map Objects from a database query to an object?` - Yes, it's called [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723). The amount of similar questions I see on SO about this on a daily basis makes me think Microsoft does not publicize it's [Data Access Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937685.aspx) very well.

Comment: Agreed, ORM is the way to go. You could use EF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82644/can-you-use-microsoft-entity-framework-with-oracle

Comment: NHibernate is another great option

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe this tool requires you to know the database and the object inside of it ahead of times. In my scenario, I know what the database will look like; however, I will not know where the database is before run time. I will edit the question to add this information. I do think that ORM is a very helpful suggestion though, so +1.

Comment: If the data is always the same, and the source varies, then EF or NHibernate will still work just fine. You just need to dynamically pass in your connection string, instead of hard coding it in app/web.config or as a variable.

Comment: This is a really cool utility; however, my manager believes this will cause security issues, therefore I cannot use it. Thanks for all the help though guys, it seems I'm forced to reinvent the wheel. If you guys have any feedback on the extension method though and pitfalls I should watch out for, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a slightly better way, you could designate the bound property like Telerik does: with a Linq expression. Here is the usage. Instead of :

```
AddBind("CreatedBy", "Created_by");
```

You would write

```
AddBind( x => x.CreatedBy, "Created_by");
```

You get a slightly stronger typing opportunity. The signature of `AddBind` would be:

```
public void AddBind<T>(Expression<Func<Account, T>> variable, string columnName) {
    // ...
}
```

But I would not go into the way of generic functions. I'd rather overload a non-generic function :

```
public void AddBind(Expression<Func<Account, double>> variable, string columnName) {
    // Add binding for double
}

public void AddBind(Expression<Func<Account, DateTime>> variable, string columnName) {
    // Add binding for DateTime
}

// ...
```

The type of binding would then be selected according to the type of your mapped object. This prevents you from misnaming your properties, so you keep the possibility of performing name changes in the `Account` class without breaking your bindings.

The column name has still to be a `string`, sorry.

Of course, the way then to generalize is to make your `BindingMap` generic. (Taking your business class as a type parameter)

```
class BindingMap<BusinessClass> {
  // ....

    public void AddBind(Expression<Func<BusinessClass, double>> variable, string columnName) {
        // Add binding for double
    }

    public void AddBind(Expression<Func<BusinessClass, DateTime>> variable, string columnName) {
        // Add binding for DateTime
    }

    // ... 
};
```

I leave as an exercice to you the problem of digging the property descriptor out of the expression :)